# Switch .js file in multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple html pages as `dashboard.html, page1.html, page2.html, page3.html` etc... and two .js files, namely `example1.js` and `example2.js` file

**

> From below example (`dashboard.html`) file, If I click on Load File 1
>   link, this page and other html pages(page1.html, page2.html etc...)
>   should replace the `default.js` file with `example1.js` file in all
>   remaining html pages until I come back to dashboard page and change to
>   other.

**

**I am fine with using external libraries**

Please check the example code below for the same...

**PS**: I am newbie to script, please help me out

**dashboard.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Switch js file</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="javascript:;" id="loadExample1">Load File 1</a> | <a href="javascript:;" id="loadExample2">Load File 2</a>

    <h1>Default js file loaded successfully!</h1>

    <a href="Page1.html">Go to Page 1</a>

    <a href="Page2.html">Go to Page 2</a>

</body>
</html>
```

**page1.html, page2.html...**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Switch js file</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Default js file loaded successfully!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**example1.js**

```
$('h1').html('Example1.js file loaded successfully!');
```

**example2.js**

```
$('h1').html('Example2.js file loaded successfully!');
```

Comment: you could try https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: Such configs are usually made on the server side, as client-side js in one document can't affect another documents (read different html files).
There's a way thou. You could use cookies https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie to store information on what script to load in users browser. Then you could add a script to check for this cookie and load needed script after the pageload.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jquery's getScript function, to asynchronously retrieve the desired javascript file to your page:

```
$("someButton").click(function(){
  $.getScript("someScriptFile.js");
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to say. But yeah you can use Jquery's getScript function, to asynchronously retrieve the desired javascript file to your page